# Use grouping and case after if statement in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

My database is something like this, but this is a demo:

```
id | pkg_name  | pkg_value
1  | package 1 | 1200
2  | package 2 | 1200
3  | package 3 | 1200
4  | package 4 | 1200
5  | master    | 1400
6  | master    | 1500
```

And here is what I want to query:

1. If one item is listed 2 or more times it counts as 2 only.
2. If it's listed only 1 time so it counts as 1 only.

How can I build this query?

The query I created to count all field and group is as below:

```
SELECT pkg_name, count(*) from packages GROUP by pkg_name
```

Comment: I Need In Result Count Of Al Package_value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT 
   pkg_name, 
   IF(COUNT(*)<=2, COUNT(*), 2) AS total
from packages GROUP by pkg_name
```

This should work, but there is likely a more optimized version that doesn't execute the count twice.

Comment: I don't think the count would be executed twice, but rather once, cached somewhere, and then evaluated twice.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks; guess it may not be as inefficient as I feared then.

Comment: Thank You So Much.
It Works

Comment: I Update Like This 

SELECT 
   pkg_value, 
   IF(COUNT(*)<=2, COUNT(*), 2) AS total
from packages GROUP by pkg_pkg_value

how can i get In result count of all pkg_value

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `CASE` expression which maps the package count to 1 if the underlying count be 1, otherwise to 2 for a count of 2 or more.

```
SELECT
    pkg_name,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS pkg_cnt
FROM packages
GROUP BY
    pkg_name
```

Comment: What If There is Date Insted pkg_name ?
its Work?

Comment: I don't follow your question, because your table has not date column.  The general query I gave would work with _any_ grouping column, assuming the query you wrote is valid.